# bathroom double wall lights on and off

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

we have two bathroom wall lights on the same switch. the lights are left and right of our above sink mirror.  All of a sudden only one of the two lights will go on at a time. already tried trouble shooting with new bulbs.

Comment: What type of fixture? What type of bulbs? What type of switch? What type of mains wiring? Revise to give us a little more to work with, please.

Comment: What do you mean by "only one...at a time"? Sometimes one and sometimes the other? Or "one works all the time and the other doesn't work at all"?